# I cannot rename a new created folder

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Just downloaded VS 2015 CTP and attempted to add a new folder using the context menu.  Well it added "NewFolder", but would not give me an option to rename it or delete it for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

VS2015 is still in preview, things like this are expected.
File a bug report so that MS know it need fixed and delete the file via windows explorer.

Comment: I am unable to file a bug report via VS 2015.  Is there another way outside of VS?

Comment: The goal of this Preview version is to collect your feedback. To report a bug, please use Connect.

Comment: I have this same problem with Version 14.0.23107.0 D145 REL